# Is the relation $R:=\{(1,2),(1,3)\}$ transitive on $M=\{1,2,3\}$ with $R\subseteq M\times M$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

> Is the relation $R:=\{(1,2),(1,3)\}$ transitive on $M=\{1,2,3\}$ with $R\subseteq M\times M$?

I think it's transitive, because we don't have elements that satisfy $xRy \land yRz $ and therefore $\forall x,y,z \in M: xRy \land yRz \implies xRz$ is always true. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. In this kind of situation you can say that it’s *vacuously* true.

Comment: Alternatively: There are no such $x,y,z$ of $M$ where $x\operatorname R y\wedge y\operatorname R z\wedge \neg(x\operatorname R z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is transitive, and this is vacuously true for the reason you have said.